# Keycloak Logout Request

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak

I wanted to ask if there is a way to logout from `keycloak` via a single http request.

I already tried to POST `/protocol/openid-connect/logout` or `/tokens/logout`, but the result is always a ORIGIN-Problem.

But the calling ORIGIN is configured in keycloak and the login with a request works.

Any chance here to logout without redirecting or open another window?

Best regards and thanks! :)

Comment: I do have exact the same problem an no solution so far.

Comment: I find similar questions, but no answers :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508917/keycloak-logout-via-keycloak-security-proxy

Comment: What RP do you use? the logout is the RP functionality

Answer (score 36):

**From the [official documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#logout):**

> You can log out of a web application in multiple ways. For Java EE
>   servlet containers, you can call `HttpServletRequest.logout()`.
>
> For other browser applications, you can redirect the browser to
>   `http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri`, which logs you out if you have an SSO session with your browser.

To get the exact URL of the app (host, realm and redirect_uri configuration):

- Log in to your Keycloak user account
- Open up the developer console of the browser
- Perform the logout operation
- Note down the URL that was used to request for logout
- Use the same URL from your application to perform the logout

Comment: This is for OpenId Connect .. may you needed to logout for another SSO protocoal (e.g. SAML)?

Comment: Hi I find that after logging out, if I have "stolen" the access tokens, I can still use it! Is this desired behavior, or unexpected? Thanks!

Comment: What's worse, the client, after logout, can even use refreshtoken to get a new accesstoken, thus the logout does nothing!

Comment: It depends on what adaptor you have used to connect to Keycloak with.  I used the javascript adaptor, you use the logout method from keycloak object to logout  and not a url.

Answer (score 6):

If you are not creating your own adaptor, but using e.g. an OpenID certified library, you might want to use that library to logout, because otherwise, as  ch271828n describes, you might logout from Keycloak but retain the session and access tokens...

In my case, I was using openresty and [lua-resty-openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc)

Accessing the keycloack logout url `https://<keycloak-server>/auth/realms/<my-realm>/protocol/openid-connect/logout` (as detailed in @aName's answer) is done by lua after we access the opts.logout_path at `https://<our-nginx-server>/service/logout`

So after setting up everything correctly, **all we have to do to logout is use the logout for our OpenID client** at `https://<our-nginx-server>/service/logout`. This will destroy the session and log us out both from the client and Keycloak.

I think I had to set `opts.revoke_tokens_on_logout` to `true`, Also note that from my experiments, for some reason, setting up a `redirect_after_logout_uri` may result in the user not signing out due to redirections.

Here is an example of what I needed to have for nginx.conf to make this work....

```
location /myservice/ {

    access_by_lua_block {
        local opts = {
            redirect_uri_path = "/myservice/auth",
            discovery = "https://<keycloak-server>/auth/realms/<my-realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            client_id = "<my-client-id>",
            client_secret = "<the-clients-secret>",
            logout_path = "/service/logout",
            revoke_tokens_on_logout = true,
            session_contents = {id_token=true} -- this is essential for safari!
        }
        -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
        local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)

        if err then
            ngx.status = 403
            ngx.say(err)
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
        end
    }

    # I disbled caching so the browser won't cache the site.
    expires           0;
    add_header        Cache-Control private;

    proxy_pass http://my-service-server.cloud:port/some/path/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```