# Keycloack: After logout, the access token can still be used

Tags: keycloak, openid, openresty

I have an nginx/openresty client to a keycloack server for authorization using openid.
I am using [lua-resty-openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc) to allow access to services behind the proxy.

The user can access his profile at
`https://<my-server>/auth/realms/<real-name>/account`
and logout through
`https://<my-server>/auth/realms/<real-name>/protocol/openid-connect/logout`

The problem is that, even after logout, the user can still access the services behind the server, basically it seems the token he gets from keycloak is still valid or something.... This is also a behaviour that has been observed by other users, see for example [this question on how to logout from keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108782/keycloak-logout-request/39014937) the comments from ch271828n

How can I ensure that after logout the user will no longer be able to get access until he logs in anew?

Comment: Maybe this article will help https://www.baeldung.com/logout-spring-security-oauth

Comment: Just for clarity: we do expire refreshToken, but accessToken IS STILL VALID while "Access Token Lifespan" time. Next time user tries to renew access token passing refresh token, Keycloak returns 400 Bad request, what should be catch and send as 401 Unauthorised response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to check the [lua source code](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc/blob/master/lib/resty/openidc.lua), but I think I have figured the logout behaviour out: Lua-resty-openidc establishes sessions, and they are terminated when a specific url access is detected (it is controlled by `opts.logout_path` which we will need to be set to an address in the path of service, e.g. .../service/logout)

In essence, there are two urls that need to be hit, one for keycloack logout, and one for openresty session logout. Accessing the keycloack logout url `https://<keycloak-server>/auth/realms/<my-realm>/protocol/openid-connect/logout` is done by lua after we access the opts.logout_path at `https://<our-nginx-server>/service/logout`

So **after setting up everything correctly**, **all we have to do to logout is** hit `https://<our-nginx-server>/service/logout`. This will destroy the session and log us out.

I think we need to set `opts.revoke_tokens_on_logout` to `true`, Also note that from my experiments, for some reason, setting up a `redirect_after_logout_uri` may result in the user not signing out due to redirections.

Here is an example of what we need to have for nginx.conf to make this work....

```
location /myservice/ {

    access_by_lua_block {
        local opts = {
            redirect_uri_path = "/myservice/auth",
            discovery = "https://<keycloak-server>/auth/realms/<my-realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            client_id = "<my-client-id>",
            client_secret = "<the-clients-secret>",
            logout_path = "/service/logout",
            revoke_tokens_on_logout = true,
            session_contents = {id_token=true} -- this is essential for safari!
        }
        -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
        local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)

        if err then
            ngx.status = 403
            ngx.say(err)
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
        end
    }

    # I disbled caching so the browser won't cache the site.
    expires           0;
    add_header        Cache-Control private;

    proxy_pass http://my-service-server.cloud:port/some/path/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```