# Change Keycloak logout redirect url

Tags: keycloak

I would like to set a Keycloak redirect url. After click on Sign out button in **template.ftl** template which is set in account directory
It is represented by list item:

```
<li><a href="${url.logoutUrl}">${msg("doSignOut")}</a></li>
```

How it is now:

- I'm redirect to the main site of keycloak (actually it is a site of login into keycloak)

What I want:

- change this site and redirect user to main page of project. How can I define it as

I use Keycloak version 12.0.2
I haven't found any appropriate settings in realmName.json file or Administration Console which is available at `http://localhost:8088/auth/admin/master/console/#/realms/realmName`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycloak Logout Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108782/keycloak-logout-request)